# Trying to create function for package that automatically plots the response of a variable for a given model when there are categorical variables

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to create a function that plots the response of a chosen variable when at least one of the variables is categorical.

When all of your variables are numerical, what I usually do is that I keep all the other variables at their mean, and then vary the target variable, here is an example with mtcars:

```
library(tidyverse)

data("mtcars")
```

First I will modify the am variable to have it as a categorical variable

```
mt2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(am = case_when(am == 0 ~ "Automatic", am == 1 ~ "Manual")) %>% select(mpg, am, wt, hp)
```

Then I will show what works for me

#### This works

for a model with only numeric variables, I have no problem for example with this model

```
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mt2)
```

I can use this function I made

```
Plot_Response <- function(Model, variable){

  # generate a data.frame with all the means copied 20 times
  Means <- Model$model %>% summarise_all(mean)
  Means <- Means[rep(seq_len(nrow(Means)), each = 20),]

  # Then generate a vector with a sequence from the min value to the max value of the variable
  MinMax <- Model$model %>% select(variable) %>% pull(variable) %>% range()
  MinMax <- seq(from = MinMax[1], to = MinMax[2], along.with = Means[,1])

  # Replace the column of the variable that we need to plot the response plot of by this sequence

  Means[colnames(Means)== as.character(variable)] <- MinMax

  ## Predict the fit and SE

  Means$Predicted <-predict(Model, newdata = Means)
  Means$SE <- predict(Model, newdata = Means, se.fit = T)$se.fit

  ## Plot the response
  result <- ggplot(Means, aes_string(x= variable, y = "Predicted")) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymax= Predicted + SE, ymin = Predicted - SE), fill = "grey") + geom_line() + theme_classic() 

  return(result)
}
```

If I use this function with the model above, I can make this graph

```
Plot_Response(Model = model1, variable = "wt")
```

[image]

### Here is when I get into trouble

Of course, if I try this when there is a categorical variable I have problems, since if it tries to get the mean of a categorical value for the data frame it fails:

```
model2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + am, data = mt2)
```

If I try

```
Plot_Response(Model = model2, variable = "wt")
```

I will get:

```
Error: variable 'am' was fitted with type "character" but type "numeric" was supplied
```

So I tried the following:

```
Plot_Response2 <- function(Model, variable){

  # First I get the names of all categorical variables
  Categoricals <- Model$model %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% select_if(is.character) %>% colnames()

  # generate a data.frame with all the means copied 20 times for each level

   Means <- Model$model %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% group_by_if(is.character) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% ungroup()
   Means <- Means[rep(seq_len(nrow(Means)), each = 20),]  %>% arrange_if(is.character) %>% group_split(substitute(variable))

  return(Means)
}
```

My idea is that the function will detect which variables are categorical. If I ask for the response of a numerical variable, I get the response of that variable in each level of the categorical variable, My problem so far is that when I do group_split it does not recognize the variable

### What I expect:

#### Example 1

I expect that if I do:

```
Plot_Response2(Model = model2, variable = "wt")
```

I will get:

[image]

I made the following code for that, but haven't been able to add it to the function:

```
Means <- model2$model %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% group_by_if(is.character) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% ungroup()
Means <- Means[rep(seq_len(nrow(Means)), each = 20),]  %>% arrange_if(is.character) %>% group_split(am)

MinMax <- model2$model %>% select(wt) %>% pull(wt) %>% range()
MinMax <- seq(from = MinMax[1], to = MinMax[2], length.out = 20)

for(i in 1:length(Means)){
  Means[[i]]$wt <- MinMax
}

Means <- bind_rows(Means)
Means$Predicted <- predict(model2, Means)
Means$SE <- predict(model2, Means, se.fit = T)$se.fit

ggplot(Means, aes(x = wt, y = Predicted)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Predicted + SE, ymin = Predicted - SE, fill = am), alpha = 0.5) + geom_line(aes(color = am)) + theme_classic()
```

#### Example 1

I expect that if I do:

```
Plot_Response2(Model = model2, variable = "am")
```

I will get:

[image]

Again for that, I used this code, which I can't seem to get together with function 2

```
Means <- model2$model %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% group_by_if(is.character) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% ungroup()
Means <- Means[rep(seq_len(nrow(Means)), each = 20),]  %>% arrange_if(is.character) %>% group_split(am)

Means <- bind_rows(Means)
Means$Predicted <- predict(model2, Means)
Means$SE <- predict(model2, Means, se.fit = T)$se.fit

ggplot(Means, aes(x = am, y = Predicted)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Predicted - SE, ymax = Predicted + SE)) + geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

Comment: Maybe checkout the [sjPlot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_interactions.html)  which does a lot of this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version that uses a few more tidyverse functions just to make things easier.

```
Plot_Response <- function(Model, variable, N=20) {
  model_data <- model.frame(Model)
  stopifnot(variable %in% names(model_data))

  # get all variables we need to dummy values for
  all_vars <- model_data %>% select(-one_of(variable))
  num_vars <- all_vars %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% summarize_all(mean)
  cat_vars <- all_vars %>% select_if(Negate(is.numeric)) %>% purrr::map(unique)

  resp_var <- model_data %>% pull(variable) 
  if(is.numeric(resp_var)) {
    resp_vals <- seq(min(resp_var), max(resp_var), length.out=N)
  } else {
    resp_vals <- unique(resp_var)
  }

  new_data <- tidyr::crossing(num_vars, !!!cat_vars, !!variable:=resp_vals)

  pred <- broom::augment(Model, newdata = new_data, se_fit=TRUE)

  ## Plot the response
  my_aes <- aes(x= !!sym(variable), y = .fitted)
  if (length(cat_vars)==1) {
    my_aes[["fill"]] <- sym(names(cat_vars))
  } else if (length(cat_vars)>1) {
    my_aes[["fill"]] <- quo(interaction(!!!syms(names(cat_vars))))
  }
  range_aes <- aes(ymax= .fitted + .se.fit, ymin = .fitted - .se.fit)
  result <- ggplot(pred, my_aes) + theme_classic() + ylab("Predicted")
  if(is.numeric(resp_var)) {
    result + 
      (if (length(cat_vars)>0) {
        geom_ribbon(range_aes) 
      } else {
        geom_ribbon(range_aes, fill="grey")
      }) + 
      geom_line()
  } else {
    result + 
      geom_errorbar(range_aes) + 
      geom_point() 
  } 

}
```

This works for both the cases you listed

```
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + am, data = mt2)
Plot_Response(model1, "wt")
Plot_Response(model1, "am")
```

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, I even got to learn abuout crossing, which I didn´t know about. You had all I needed

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are describing **exactly** the sort of problem solved by the package [DescTools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DescTools). The first line of the package description says it very well:

> DescTools is an extensive collection of miscellaneous basic statistics
>   functions and comfort wrappers not available in the R basic system for
>   efficient description of data.

I am not a fan of loading up a string of packages to get a job done in R. However, I make an exception for this one. I think the extensive collection of tools by Andri Signorell is truly outstanding. There may be conflicts between the functions defined in `DescTools` and those in the `tidyverse` so I frame my answer without resorting to `tidyverse`.

```
# DescTools needs to be available
  if (!require(DescTools)) {
    install.packages("DescTools")
  }
  library(DescTools)

# Create factors in mtcars
  mt3 <- mtcars
  mt3$am <- factor(mt3$am, labels = c("man", "auto"))
  mt3$vs <- factor(mt3$vs, labels = c("v", "str"))
```

The examples provided in the question are variations on plotting `mpg` as described by various other variables. If the objective here is actually to code a general function for that purpose, then this answer is of no use. However, if the objective is to conveniently visualize variables as stated, "I wish to get a function that automatically finds which variables are categorical, which are continuous and plots the response accordingly," then I think `DescTools` is a great answer!

`DescTools` is not general purpose plotting tool. I don't believe you can plot simultaneous regressions as done with the `ggplot` code. However, it excels at showing you a sensible plot for the selected variables. First, the two examples requested:

```
# mpg as a function of weight
  dev.new(width = 6, height = 4.5)
  opar <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
  Desc(mpg ~ wt, mt3, main = "Manual", subset = am == "man")
  Desc(mpg ~ wt, mt3, main = "Automatic", subset = am == "auto")
  par(opar)
```

[image: mpg by wt]

```
# mpg as a function of transmission
  Desc(mpg ~ am, mt3)
```

[image: mpg vs transmission]
And two more examples of how simple this can be for interacting factors and even for a single continuous variable.

```
  Desc(mpg ~ am:vs, mt3)
  Desc(mt3$qsec)
```

[image: mpg vs interaction]
[image: quarter mile time]